# How to append the output variables of a shell script to excel file

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I have a script that runs daily at 11 PM and produces variables

$endofday_A which will have value "20:03:06"
$endofday_B which will have value "20:06:07"
$endofday_C which will have value "20:05:25"
.
.
.
and so on

Now I want this values saved in an excel file(endofday_A, endofday_B endofday_C names as column names)

I don't know how it can be carried out as I will get output everyday and has to be appended to the already existing excel file.

I know this is too complicated, but please can anyone help me on this, would be greatly appreciated. I need only in shell script(.ksh)

Comment: Sounds difficult and complicated. Much easier to do by modifying a .csv file, which can be opened in Excel or any other spreadsheet application. You can save a copy of the latest file as an .xls or .xlsx file if you need an Excel file for some particular reason.

Comment: Write the values as CSV files in a directory and setup the ODBC Text Driver. Next, create a database query in Excel to get the current values.

Comment: I won't mind if it is a csv file. But can I have the script to start with?